# Static methods and thread safety in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I understand that static method does not guarantee thread safety. Because even though there is a single class method in the entire application, that method  can be called simultaneously and could cause thread safety issues if you are not careful. But what happens when that class method doesn't affect any global variable? Is is still Thread Safe? For example, I have this code:

```
public static String convertToString(int i) {
    return String.valueOf(i);
}
```

If 2 or more threads were to call this method simultaneously, is it thread safe?

Comment: "*If 2 or more threads were to call this method simultaneously, is it thread safe?*" - Yes.

Comment: this has a question and answer already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910976/how-to-ensure-thread-safety-of-utility-static-method#targetText=It%20is%20well%20known%20that,and%20mutable%20objects%20are%20not.&targetText=But%20that's%20a%20different%20matter,operates%20only%20on%20its%20arguments.

Comment: There's no shared state, so yes.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that link. It gave a clear and concise answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that method is thread-safe.  The issue with thread-safety occurs is when the static method tries to do something more complex, like sharing data.

Going in more detail,

```
public static String convertToString(int i) {
    return String.valueOf(i);
}
```

the above method operates only on the parameter `i`, which resides on the stack.  Stack is local to the thread, so it is perfectly thread-safe.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is thread safe. As long as static method above does not read/modify shared mutable reference or value. For example:-

```
private static int counter = 0;

public static String convertToString(int i) {

    //this has race conditions.
    counter++;

    return String.valueOf(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need synchronization when you are performing [non atomic operations](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html#atomic-operation) like incrementing variable (`i++`) - update it's value, then read etc.

Such operation like reading value (be careful with `double` and `long`) is an atomic operation by definition so it's thread-safe

Comment: Your wording on this part is a little bit ambiguous. One could read it as: "`i++` is an atomic operation".